# Why is requestAnimationFrame not matching monitor refresh rate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, requestanimationframe

This isn't an urgent question but I noticed that requestAnimationFrame is being called 168 times a second on my browser. I know that it is meant to match my monitor refresh rate (240hz) but it isn't. This doesn't only happen on the Canvas which Chrome uses my Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 for so I'm thinking it is a CPU limitation (Intel core i7 8700). Any thoughts on what this could be?

EDIT: Its working now without me changing anything but I'm still curious what's wrong. It wasn't really an issue just something that was confusing me.

Comment: There's no spec that insists on any particular behavior for that API.

Comment: What happens in your callbacks?

Comment: @Kaiido it isn't specifically about my code. The UFO FPS comparison (you may or may not be familiar with it but here it is: [https://www.testufo.com/]) uses this to detect FPS so i programmed my own to check and I got the same. Today it is working and I don't know why because it wasn't earlier but I always knew the monitor was working from other tests, just browsers were misreporting it.

Comment: @TOGD at 240hz js only has 4ms per frame, that's really not much, so anything that will pump on the CPU at the same time may make it unable to reach that rate.